# git-svn track files in git, but do not commit them to svn

Tags: git-svn

I want to track files in git locally, but not commit them to the SVN repository.  Is this possible?

My reasoning for doing so is that I have some configuration files in a directory that is tracked by SVN (or git svn in my case).  I'd like to track those files in git so I can quickly merge changes easily.

Comment: You could create a new git branch that contains these files.

Comment: Yes, I have done that, but the problem is when I branch off of that and then merge back into 'master', it will want to pull those changes in.